# After updating visual studio to 16.11.1 swagger outputting Failed to load API definition error .The project (.Net )worked properly before the update

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

After updating visual studio to 16.11.1 swagger outputting **Failed to load API definition** error.
The project (Asp.Net core web API )worked properly before the update and working in other systems.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Mlw.png)

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try to create a new api project with the v16.11.1 visual studio to see if the swagger ui can work?